# Passing Parameter Variable To Outside

Tags: javascript

CategoryModel.find, gathers all records inside a db. Error if something goes wrong and categories is my output array.

```
categoryModel.find(function(error, categories) {
  if(error){
    console.log(error)
  }
});
```

I need to reach that categories outside of the function.

```
var result = categoryModel.find(function(error, categories) {
  if(error){
    console.log(error)
  }
  console.log(categories)
});

console.log(result.categories)
```

This type is not working. Im beginner at javascript :( Thanks

## SOLVED

```
var result = {}
categoryModel.find(function(err, categories) {
  console.log(categories)
  result = categories
  callback(result)
});

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Hello `async` my old friend....

Comment: I guess i have to use callback function?

Comment: what does `categoryModel` actually return?

Comment: A json array which contains output from db

Comment: I mean what do you get if you output `result`?

Comment: i ll make some changes in another function

Answer (score 0):

Like @briosheje said in the comment, you should use async / await.

For your case, it would look like this:

```
async function someFunction() {
  var result = await categoryModel.find();
  if (result.error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
  console.log(result.categories);
}
```

You can read more about async / await [there](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).